# awesomium get ElementById VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, getelementbyid, awesomium

Please help me to getElementById using VB.NET

```
Dim document = CType(WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document"), Awesomium.Core.JSObject)

Dim myele = document.getElementById("ask-question-link")
```

I have used this code but it says, getElementById is not a member of Awesomium.Core.JSObject  Please help me

PS: Im trying for VB.NET code
Its working well for C#

Here is the C# code working

```
dynamic document = (Awesomium.Core.JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
var myele = document.getElementById("ask-question-link");
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post the C# code you have that is working?

Comment: thank you for your support. Here is the working c# code


 dynamic document = (Awesomium.Core.JSObject)webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
            var myele = document.getElementById("ask-question-link");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dim Question As String = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementById('ask-question-link')")